# Os-prober does not detects Fedora (even though I am currently booted into Fedora 38!)

Tags: ubuntu, fedora, grub2, dual-boot

As shown below, the os-prober does not detects Fedora (even though I am currently booted into Fedora!)

```bash
$ sudo os-prober
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Data:Ubuntu 22.10 (22.10):Ubuntu:linux
File descriptor 3 (/dev/pts/0) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 22190: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[188726]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 22190: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (/dev/pts/0) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 22190: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[188726]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 22190: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (/dev/pts/0) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 22244: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[188726]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 22244: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (/dev/pts/0) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 22244: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[188726]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 22244: grub2-probe
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-UbuntuRoot:Ubuntu 23.04 (23.04):Ubuntu1:linux
```

```
[root@lamyer EFI]# sudo grub2-mkconfig -o "/boot/grub2/grub2-efi.cfg"
Generating grub configuration file ...
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[207085]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 27412: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[205344]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 27412: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[207085]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 27412: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[205344]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 27412: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[207085]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 27474: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[205344]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 27474: grub2-probe
File descriptor 3 (pipe:[207085]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 27474: grub2-probe
File descriptor 9 (pipe:[205344]) leaked on vgs invocation. Parent PID 27474: grub2-probe
Found Ubuntu 22.10 (22.10) on /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-Data
Found Ubuntu 23.04 (23.04) on /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-UbuntuRoot
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

## Any suggestions?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I thought the idea of `os-prober` was to find operating systems *other than* the one you are running in